# Angularjs app crashes with "Error: too much recursion" when defining a route

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

I'm following this tutorial on using angularjs alongside laravel: http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/11/working-with-laravel-plus-angular-part-2/. However, if I define a route in config.routes.js which points to a controller, any controller, my app crashes. In the console the error "Error: too much recursion" comes up, along with a useless stack trace.

All my files are exactly the same as in the tutorial, I only changed the name of the route and the controller, but that shouldn't make a difference.

I googled around a bit and it seems this error might be caused by using a wrong version of jquery. I use angularjs 1.3.0 and I have no idea which jquery version my app is using, but I used `npm install angular`, so it'd be weird if that installed a wrong version, right?

I'm completely lost on why this happens and also very frustrated, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT: Added code:

app/js/config.routes.js

```
angular.module('app').config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider)
{
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');

    $routeProvider.when('/transactions', 
    {
        templateUrl: 'features/transactions/transactions.tpl.html',
        controller: 'Transactions'
    });
});
```

app/js/transactions/transactions.js:

```
angular.module('app').controller('Transactions', function($scope, $http)
{
    $http.get('/api/transactions').then(function(result) 
    {
        $scope.shows = result.data;
    });
});
```

transactions.tpl.html is empty.

app.js:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
```

EDIT 2: added gulp.js
The only thing I changed here is, is that I added the 'webserver' task.

```
var gulp    = require('gulp');
var fs      = require('fs');
var plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var es      = require('event-stream');
var del     = require('del');

var publicFolderPath = '../public';

var paths = {
  appJavascript:     ['app/js/app.js', 'app/js/**/*.js'],
  appTemplates:      'app/js/**/*.tpl.html',
  appMainSass:       'app/scss/main.scss',
  appStyles:         'app/scss/**/*.scss',
  appImages:         'app/images/**/*',
  indexHtml:         'app/index.html',
  vendorJavascript:  ['vendor/js/angular.js', 'vendor/js/**/*.js'],
  vendorCss:         ['vendor/css/**/*.css'],
  finalAppJsPath:    '/js/app.js',
  finalAppCssPath:   '/css/app.css',
  specFolder:        ['spec/**/*_spec.js'],
  publicFolder:      publicFolderPath,
  publicJavascript:  publicFolderPath + '/js',
  publicAppJs:       publicFolderPath + '/js/app.js',
  publicCss:         publicFolderPath + '/css',
  publicImages:      publicFolderPath + '/images',
  publicIndex:       publicFolderPath + '/angular.html',
  publicJsManifest:  publicFolderPath + '/js/rev-manifest.json',
  publicCssManifest: publicFolderPath + '/css/rev-manifest.json'
};

gulp.task('scripts-dev', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.vendorJavascript.concat(paths.appJavascript, paths.appTemplates))
    .pipe(plugins.if(/html$/, buildTemplates()))
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(plugins.concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.publicJavascript));
});
gulp.task('scripts-prod', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.vendorJavascript.concat(paths.appJavascript, paths.appTemplates))
    .pipe(plugins.if(/html$/, buildTemplates()))
    .pipe(plugins.concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(plugins.ngAnnotate())
    .pipe(plugins.uglify())
    .pipe(plugins.rev())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.publicJavascript))
    .pipe(plugins.rev.manifest({path: 'rev-manifest.json'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.publicJavascript));
});

gulp.task('styles-dev', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.vendorCss.concat(paths.appMainSass))
    .pipe(plugins.if(/scss$/, plugins.sass()))
    .pipe(plugins.concat('app.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.publicCss));
});

gulp.task('styles-prod', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.vendorCss.concat(paths.appMainSass))
    .pipe(plugins.if(/scss$/, plugins.sass()))
    .pipe(plugins.concat('app.css'))
    .pipe(plugins.minifyCss())
    .pipe(plugins.rev())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.publicCss))
    .pipe(plugins.rev.manifest({path: 'rev-manifest.json'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.publicCss));
});

gulp.task('images', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.appImages)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.publicImages));
});

gulp.task('indexHtml-dev', ['scripts-dev', 'styles-dev'], function() {
  var manifest = {
    js: paths.finalAppJsPath,
    css: paths.finalAppCssPath
  };

  return gulp.src(paths.indexHtml)
    .pipe(plugins.template({css: manifest['css'], js: manifest['js']}))
    .pipe(plugins.rename(paths.publicIndex))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.publicFolder));
});

gulp.task('indexHtml-prod', ['scripts-prod', 'styles-prod'], function() {
  var jsManifest  = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(paths.publicJsManifest, 'utf8'));
  var cssManifest = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(paths.publicCssManifest, 'utf8'));

  var manifest = {
    js: '/js/' + jsManifest['app.js'],
    css: '/css/' + cssManifest['app.css']
  };

  return gulp.src(paths.indexHtml)
    .pipe(plugins.template({css: manifest['css'], js: manifest['js']}))
    .pipe(plugins.rename(paths.publicIndex))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.publicFolder));
});

gulp.task('lint', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.appJavascript.concat(paths.specFolder))
    .pipe(plugins.jshint())
    .pipe(plugins.jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'));
});

gulp.task('testem', function() {
  return gulp.src(['']) // We don't need files, that is managed on testem.json
    .pipe(plugins.testem({
      configFile: 'testem.json'
    }));
});

gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
  del([paths.publicJavascript, paths.publicImages, paths.publicCss, paths.publicIndex], {force: true}, cb);
});

gulp.task('watch', ['indexHtml-dev', 'images'], function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.appJavascript, ['lint', 'scripts-dev']);
  gulp.watch(paths.appTemplates, ['scripts-dev']);
  gulp.watch(paths.vendorJavascript, ['scripts-dev']);
  gulp.watch(paths.appImages, ['images-dev']);
  gulp.watch(paths.specFolder, ['lint']);
  gulp.watch(paths.indexHtml, ['indexHtml-dev']);
  gulp.watch(paths.appStyles, ['styles-dev']);
  gulp.watch(paths.vendorCss, ['styles-dev']);
});

gulp.task('webserver', ['indexHtml-dev', 'images-dev'], function() {
  plugins.connect.server({
    root: paths.tmpFolder,
    port: 5000,
    livereload: true,
    middleware: function(connect, o) {
      return [ (function() {
        var url = require('url');
        var proxy = require('proxy-middleware');
        var options = url.parse('http://localhost:8000/api');
        options.route = '/api';
        return proxy(options);
      })(), historyApiFallback ];
    }
  });
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
gulp.task('production', ['scripts-prod', 'styles-prod', 'images', 'indexHtml-prod']);

function buildTemplates() {
  return es.pipeline(
    plugins.minifyHtml({
      empty: true,
      spare: true,
      quotes: true
    }),
    plugins.angularTemplatecache({
      module: 'app'
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: angular has no dependency on jquery. Please show relevant code if you want help

Comment: Added the (I think) relevant pieces of code.

Comment: my guess is you are missing this - $routeProvider.otherwise('/transactions');

Comment: Nope that also doesn't work. I added my gulp.js file, maybe the problem is in there?

Comment: Your app crashes *when*? On startup? On hitting a page? During build?

Comment: Whenever I try to access a route defined in config.routes.js. It doesn't matter what's in the controller for that route, only that it exists. If the controller doesn't exist the app doesn't crash, but it does obviously throw an error about the missing controller.